# Avoiding Appendix-Specific Reference Section while using papaja

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, papaja

I am writing a report with R Markdown and papaja in which I add an appendix by including:

```
appendix:
   - "appendix.Rmd"
```

in the YAML header.

When I include citations in the appendix, an appendix-specific reference section is created following the appendix content. Is it possible to suppress this behavior and instead include citations in the appendix in the main reference section that is shown before the appendix?

Example:

**Main Text**

some text with a citation (Someone, 2021).

**References**

Someone, A. (2021). *title*. Journal.

**Appendix**

Some text in the appendix with a citation (Someone, 2021).

Someone, A. (2021). *title*. Journal.

"Someone, A. (2021). *title*. Journal." is printed twice, once in the main reference section and once after the appendix. I would like it to only be printed in the main reference section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PDF output, you can accomplish this by including the content of your appendix in the main document. The end of your file should look similar to the following:

```
# References

\begingroup
\setlength{\parindent}{-0.5in}
\setlength{\leftskip}{0.5in}

<div id="refs" custom-style="Bibliography"></div>
\endgroup

\appendix

# My first appendix's title

As some other people said [@some_author]
```

- The lines above `\appendix` include the biblography -- the code should already be included in your file because it is part of papaja's template `.Rmd` file.
- `\appendix` then tells LaTeX to interpret all following sections as appendices.
- The code below `\appendix` can be written like standard sections, where each section is interpreted as one appendix (e.g. Appendix A, Appendix B, etc.).

Comment: This is a good workaround, thanks. Maybe it is generally better to put everything in the main document. I will keep the question open for a little longer in case someone finds a way how to achieve the same behavior when using separate appendix .Rmd files.

Comment: If you want to use separate .Rmd files for your appendices, you can use the code above and include the respective .Rmd files like you would include child documents. Just insert the respective code chunks below `\appendix`